# Obtaining JWT of a user in Keycloak

Tags: jwt, keycloak

As admin of a Keycloak server, how can I obtain access-token of a particular user without knowing his password? Unfortunately impersonation doesn't help me because it does not contain neither his id nor his username.

Answer (score 4):

There's a [feature](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/blob/master/securing_apps/topics/token-exchange/token-exchange.adoc#impersonation) starting from keycloak 3.4.0 called token exchange wich allows you to exchange an access token from a user with impersonation permission to get other token on behalf of the other user. You can use the token endpoint this way:

```
curl -X POST \
    -d "client_id=starting-client" \
    -d "client_secret=geheim" \
    --data-urlencode "grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:token-exchange" \
    -d "subject_token=...." \
    --data-urlencode "requested_token_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:access_token" \
    -d "audience=target-client" \
    -d "requested_subject=wburke" \
    http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

You might find [this post](https://blog.softwaremill.com/who-am-i-keycloak-impersonation-api-bfe7acaf051a) useful too.